# Have I lost a commit?

Tags: git, github

After some changes in my code I've noticed that I need to push this changes in a new branch, so I do:

```
$ git checkout develop
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting

$ git commit -m "Update code to follow pep8 style"
[hotfix/tests 4aadaf0] Update code to follow pep8 style
54 files changed, 455 insertions(+), 331 deletions(-)

$ git checkout develop 
Switched to branch 'develop'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.

$ git checkout -b feature/pep8-code-style
Switched to a new branch 'feature/pep8-code-style'

$ git push origin feature/pep8-code-style 
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

Here I've lost my code. Where is it?

Comment: Where did you `git add` your changes? Which branch had you checked out before? Your last checkout command creates a new branch, it does not switch to an existing one

Comment: Yes, I git add my changes before trying to checkout develop for the first time. My last checkout creates a new branch and moves me on it (-b)

Comment: Presumably in `hotfix/tests`.

Comment: Ah yes. Well spotted, sir :)

Comment: Try `--full-history`.

Comment: Try `git checkout feature/pep8-code-style` then `git merge hotfix/tests`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your changes and your commit should still be on your `hotfix/tests` branch. Nothing has been lost:

> ```
> [hotfix/tests 4aadaf0] Update code to follow pep8 style
> ```

So commit `4aadaf0` contains your pep8 style changes.